# Have to press submit twice for calling firebase function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am new to firebase. I am trying to update data to my firebase firestore db.

**Problem**: Whenever I submit the form, using the "Submit button", I have to press it twice for it to act on the firestore function [though it does do the console.log function]

**Ideal behaviour**: I should be pressing the submit button o nline once.

```
    handleSubmit(){   
            console.log(this.state);
            fb.firestore().collection("businessDetails").add({
                category: this.state.bCategory,
                description: this.state.bDescription,
                name: this.state.bName,
                since: this.state.bEstablished,
                phone: this.state.bPhone,
                uid: this.state.uid
            })
            .then(()=>{
                console.log("User succesfully submitted, data recorded");
            })
            .catch((error)=>{
                console.log(error);
            })
        }


    <Footer>
        <FooterTab>
            <Button onPress={()=>this.handleSubmit()} 
                disabled={!this.state.flag} full 
                style={(this.state.flag)?styles.submitButton:[]}
            >
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Submit and Signup</Text>
            </Button>
        </FooterTab>                        
    </Footer>
```

Comment: Suprisingly, line2 of handlesubmit() [console.log line] works on the first submit, but, not the firestore function. Have to press submit to make the firestore function work.

Comment: Is it possible that the behavior is due to the cold start of functions?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but I do not understand what "cold start of function" is. :/

Comment: Maybe this video from Doug helps you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3eG9xpzNXM

Comment: Though, the video did not provide me a solution, it did open my mind towards the problem. I fixed it by placing "fb.firestore" in the constructor, so, making sure that there is a connection with firestore when the component is mounted, decreasing the cold start time. Thanks @ConstantinBeer.

Comment: Glad it helped somehow :)